# How does jQuery's .ajax method define a 'failed' request?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

Surprisingly, the [documentation for `.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) does not appear to define the terms 'success' and 'fail' anywhere.

There are the obvious rules, for example:

- Any `4xx` or `5xx` status code will trigger `.fail()`
- Any `2xx` status code will trigger `.done()` (success)

However there appears to be some additional logic, beyond the response codes, that `.ajax` uses to decide whether a response "failed".

For example, it would appear that if the response cannot be parsed according to the chosen `dataType`, this counts as a failure.  This is especially the case, for example, if `dataType: json` is set:

> The JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error is thrown. As of jQuery 1.9, an empty response is also rejected; the server should return a response of null or {} instead.

What is the complete list of rules that jQuery uses to determine whether a request succeeded or not?

Answer (score 0):

.ajax is implemented on top of XMLHttpRequest object, which is the "javascript way" of doing ajax. And XMLHttpRequest is also, based on HTTP protocol, so you might want to check on [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) list, that can be resumed as:

- 1xx Informational message (returns ok)
- 2xx Success (returns ok)
- 3xx Redirect
- 4xx Client error (returns fail)
- 5xx Server error (returns fail)

The "logic" you're looking for is to check every response code type.

Comment: Right, but like my question points out, `.ajax` isn't guaranteed to return a success/fail solely based on the response code.  There are some other activities, like parsing the response data, that affect `.ajax`'s behavior.

Comment: ¿Have you checked the response code number in your "For example, it would appear that if the response cannot be parsed according to the chosen dataType, this counts as a failure." ? Im pretty sure it's 4xx..

Comment: The response code is 200.  I'm not looking for troubleshooting tips in this question - I am looking for a complete guide to `.ajax`'s internal logic.

Comment: @DiegoS As a reference, _400 Bad Request_ is a client side error and thus would not be used if the server returns a malformed response...